# Why my remote branches are displayed on the top of my log? (git log --graph)

Tags: git

I wanted to connect my project on a very similar project with some common files, but no common commits. So I added I remote branch to my repository

```
git remote add origin //other-project/
git remote update
```

Now my `git log --oneline --graph ...` display my remote branches on the top of my local branches:

```
* 47ad4e42 - (7 years ago) foo 2 (origin/master)
* 4d5e2435 - (7 years ago) foo 1
* 4d5e2435 - (2 minutes ago) bar (master, HEAD)    
...
```

The used log command is as follow:

```
 git log \
     --all \
     -n30 \
     --graph \
     --abbrev-commit \
     --decorate \
     --date=relative \
     --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)'
```

How can I display the remote branches not on the top of my actual work ?

I think this would be much better, since there are no common commits (yet), between the two projects.

```
* 4d5e2435 - (2 minutes ago) bar (master, HEAD)    
| * 47ad4e42 - (7 years ago) foo 2 (origin/master)
| * 4d5e2435 - (7 years ago) foo 1
| |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally `git-log` is in reverse chronological order. But `--graph` changes that. From [the `git-log` documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) for `--graph`...

> [--graph] implies the --topo-order option by default, but the --date-order option may also be specified.

From the docs for `--topo-order`...

> some older commits are shown before newer ones in order to avoid showing the commits from two parallel development track mixed together.

If you explicitly specify `--date-order` you should get what you want.